# Change in color

Tags: photons, speed-of-light, refraction

We have studied that when light changes medium, its speed along with  wavelength, changes. Does that means that if we are inside a pool of water and a red flash light is pointed towards us, it will appear us, say, green or blue? due to the wavelength of red light will shrink?

Comment: Consider that whether you're out in the air or underwater, by the time the light is detected by your eye, it's propagating in the vitreous humor of your eye (or even in the flesh of your retina), not in the air or water that's outside your eye.

Comment: This question is not related to quantum field theory. It is about physical optics. Please don't add tags for no reason. Removed them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your eyes see as color is the frequency of the light. This is because individual rhodopsin molecules interact with individual photons of a certain energy, and energy is related to frequency, not to wavelength.

The medium does change the speed and wavelength but not the frequency: Photon energy is unchanged.

So no, the color doesn’t, change due to the change in index.

That said, water does absorb some colors more than others, so white light often takes on a greenish or bluish tint.  But that’s due to red light be absorbed faster.

Comment: Dear Bob, that's a wonderful insight of photon energy concept,could you please clarify the last paragraph of your answer. Shouldn't it be that water scatters blue, green light more? Could you also provide me the rigorous source of this information like textbook/research paper etc. thank you

Comment: you said energy is related to frequency, not to wavelength.  Frequency is directly related to wavelength so energy is related to wavelength.

Comment: @jmh, photon energy doesn't change as a beam passes into a medium with a different diffractive index.

Comment: @jmh Frequency is speed/wavelength.  If the speed and wavelength are both 2/3 of what they are in vacuum, the frequency is unchanged.

Comment: @VasuGoyal How water absorbs and scatters light is interesting, but probably better as a separate Question.

Comment: @BobJacobsen , could you provide me the source of this information that rhodopsin molecule absorb energy. Any textbook, research paper would be great.

Comment: @VasuGoyal  I'd start with encyclopedias:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodopsin  https://www.britannica.com/science/rhodopsin  and more on color vision: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22541/ particularly figure 32.21